# Not able to share screen with Debian 10

Tags: debian, gnome

I have Debian 10 installed, here the info

[image: info]

When I try to share my screen during a video conference, for example using Microsoft Teams or Google Hangouts, I'm not able to do it. If I try using Teams, the program crashes. If I try with Hangouts, people only see a black screen and the cursor, nothing else.

Screen sharing in the Sharing section of my Settings is enabled, if you guess. Do I have to modify something in some configuration file?

**Edit**

I have installed Microsoft Teams Version 1.3.00.5153 (64-bit) and I'm using Wayland.

If I try with Teams on browser instead of the app, I'm not able to share the entire screen (only black image displayed) but I'm able to share each app individually. If I use the Teams app, when I click on "share screen" the app crashes.

Comment: What version of Teams are you running (Desktop or Web version too) and are you using Wayland? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/587445/edit) your post to include these details. Thank you.

Comment: @kemotep done, updated

Comment: Could you please try logging into a X user session and trying again? From what I am finding with the most up to date version of Teams on Debian 10, screen sharing only works with X11 and not Wayland.

Comment: @kemotep Thank you, it worked! Add this solution as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Microsoft Tech Community post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/debian-10-teams-share-screen-blake-crash/m-p/1068428#) points out that user's of Microsoft Teams on Linux need to make sure that they have the latest version installed and be using X11 as your graphical user session to be able to screen share.

You can switch between Wayland and X11 typically using the user session options menu on the login screen of the common Linux desktop environments.

As of the time of this post, XWayland and Wayland do not support screen sharing on Teams.

There also exists an [unofficial teams-for-linux](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux) that does support screen sharing. However, I recommend sticking with getting the official version from Microsoft directly to best receive support and updates.

Comment: It works, switch to Xorg resolved my problem. Thanks a lot.I share the official link where it was discussed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/204892/ms-teams-screen-sharing-option-not-available-ubunt.html 

To check if you are using Waylay type the following command: `loginctl show-session $(awk '/tty/ {print $1}' <(loginctl)) -p Type | awk -F= '{print $2}'`.

Answer (score 3):

In Debian testing you can now do this under Wayland without too much trouble.  Install `pipewire` and `xdg-desktop-portal-[impl]`, where [impl] depends on your choice of DE.  Then install google-chrome-beta, the beta release being needed at the time of writing for compatibility with libpipewire-0.3.  In Chrome set the `#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` flag to enabled.  That should be enough for you to share your screen from Chrome, including in Teams meetings.